# Visual Studio Code - profile that allows debugging serverside and clientside code at the same time

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying to create a VS Code launch profile that allows debugging serverside and clientside code at the same time using the new C# DevKit, I'm however failing to do so.

What I've tried is first starting the "C#: {projectname}" to debug serverside, this works. Then I've attempted to launch another configuration "Launch chrome against localhost", however my Typescript breakpoints fail to bind.

Any help?

Comment: write two launch configs probably. see also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations